# How to send POST jquery ajax calls to server using php / mysql for "favorite" button?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I'm looking to POST very simple data to a page for a "favorite" button, called "postData.php" where I already understand how to handle POST data and send it to the server. What I'm unsure of is how to set up the jquery .ajax function to make this work.

I understand that there will be

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(){}
```

for the function call, but what do I include in the function? The data sent in your example can be generic as I just need to understand jquery-ajax a little better.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The documentation would be a good place to start. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax Additionally, check out the new jquery Learning site: http://learn.jquery.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a shortcut function called `$.post()`.

```
$.post('postData.php', { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Otherwise, this is how the `$.ajax()` function is used.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'postData.php',
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: success is the function called if it is successful, right? what are different examples of dataType?

Comment: Yes, success is the callback. From the jQuery documentation, `dataType` can be `xml, json, script, or html`.

Answer (score 0):

For the event itself, assuming jQuery 1.7X or later.

```
$(document).on("click", "#myDiv", function(){
    $.post("filethatacceptspostdata.php", {'data':'object', item2:'data', item3:'data'}, function(myreturndata){
        //Whatever you want to do with myreturndata here.
        //I would have the filethatacceptspostdata.php file output a number 1 if the data was successfully stored.
    });
});
```